# What happens to dependents when primary visa holder leaves (France)

Tags: france, blue-card, dependent-visa

I am on a European Blue Card in *France* that is valid for 4 years. My wife and son are on "passeport talent-famille". I have been having trouble getting anything useful in France and am going to move. However, my wife has a job and wants to continue working.

I know that in the French system a Carte de Sejour once issued is valid till the end of its issue date. What I do not understand is what happens to my wife's work permit when I leave. The answer for any other country is obvious but France is a lot more logical and humane when it comes to immigration.

Since my wife has been working already can she continue with her work permit? If not what happens to her social security contributions? For the primary residence permit holder, even and expired card is renewed even if the person has no job for the duration of chomage so it would seem that the French shouldn't ask a working person on dependent visa to just pack and leave when the primary person leaves.